# How to safely reference directories in Makefile to prevent `rm -fr /*`?

Tags: linux, makefile

Here is the standard way I usually define `clean` target in hand-written Makefiles:

```
clean:
    rm -fr $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

If there is a typo in the variable or I forgot to define it, it will run `rm -rf /*` instead, which is not a risk I want to accept. But after having an accident when exactly this happened, I've been trying to find a better way to reference paths in Makefile in a safe way and I couldn't find it.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Prefix with `./`, i.e. `rm -fr ./$(BUILD_DIR)`, or remove trailing slash, `rm -fr $(BUILD_DIR)`. If you are doing recursive remove you don't need wildcard in path

Comment: The first solution would still delete current directory and the second deletes the entire BUILD_DIR (including any hidden file I might want to preserve).

Comment: Place your object files in an `obj` directory and then to clean object files `@rm -rf $(OBJS)` (or provide separate `rm` commands for, e.g. `*.o`). For your executables or other files in the current build directory, name them explicitly, either by name or with globbing by extensions as with `*.o` above and GET RID of the `-r` option. Narrow the scope of what you are removing and don't try and remove them all with one `rm` command. Use as many as you need under `clean:`

Comment: Assuming you are using VCS like git, deleting your current directory or build directories should not be a problem. Also this could be a reason to use CMake instead, which will generate your Makefile for you and ensure you don't fat finger your variable names.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I like that idea, you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it. It's better to explicitly define items to delete anyway, rather than clean the whole directory

Comment: @Gillespie I usually run `make` before committing to make sure, that there are no obvious errors and the program compiles. If I delete CURDIR, then I'll loose the entire commit. Using CMake is a good advice, but I was restricted to using only Makefile in this case.

Comment: I don't see how this is really related to make per se: if you had a shell script that run `rm -rf $BUILD_DIR/*` it would have the same issue.  You have to decide what error case you want to check for, then implement a check for that.  Is the error only where `BUILD_DIR` is empty?  Then don't allow that by checking for it in the makefile.  Or does `BUILD_DIR` have to be a relative path?  Or must it end with a particular directory like `.../obj`?  Or.... Only once you define that for yourself, can we suggest how to implement it.

Comment: @MadScientist in bash it is possible to write ${BUID_DIR:-/doesnotexist/}. If there is a way of doing that in Makefile, that would also be an acceptable solution.

Comment: You can add `BUILD_DIR ?= /doesnotexist/` to your makefile.  That's not QUITE the same because if someone runs `make BUILD_DIR=` with no value it will do the wrong thing.  If you really want to check for empty values the best way is to add something like: `$(if $(BUILD_DIR),,$(error Missing BUILD_DIR value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with there are many, many ways to structure a `Makefile` to make things easier to clean. Most are by personal preference, and therefore not a right or wrong issue.

In your case, the thing that stands out is the attempt to cleanup with a single `rm` command under the `clean:` phony target. It is far easier to use multiple specific `rm` commands rather than one "encompasses all" `rm -r`. As you have found, a misnamed or absent variable setting can have dire consequences when you `rm -r $(SOMEVAR)/*`.

What I generally do is put sources in the `src` subdirectory, includes in the `include` subdirectory and then have all object files output to an `obj` subdirectory. (you can also have binaries created in a `bin` directory if you like). In that case `clean:` becomes

```
clean:
    rm -rvf $(OBJ)
    rm -rvf $(BIN)
```

An easy setup that allows you to do just that is:

```
TARGET  = myexe

CC  = gcc

BIN     = bin
SRC     = src
OBJ     = obj
SRCS    = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJS    = $(patsubst $(SRC)%.c,  $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SRCS))

CFLAGS  += -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Werror -std=c11
CFLAGS  += -Iinclude
LDFLAGS +=

# combines clean and create directories before build
all:    clean setup $(TARGET)

# create directories
setup:
    @mkdir -p $(BIN)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ)

# build executable
$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)  -o $(BIN)/$(TARGET) $^

# compile objects
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# clean
clean:
    @rm -rvf $(OBJ)
    @rm -rvf $(BIN)
```

(**note:** shown for building C sources, adjust extensions as needed)

This way you never have the potential to `rm -rf $(SOMEVAR)/*` when `SOMEVAR` is undefined or empty. Good luck with your coding.